# How to Search products in Shopify API?

Tags: api, shopify

I am familiar with the doc of Shopify but I can't find how to search for a product, does anyone have an idea? I have looked at the doc http://docs.shopify.com/api/product but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use a client like Postman. Once you have your Shopify permanent access token in the correct header i.e `X-Shopify-Access-Token: {access_token}`, you can achieve this in the following way:

First grab your shop's URL in the following format:

```
exampleshop.myshopify.com/admin/products/#{id}.json
```

Then, instead of `#{id}` put in the `id` of the product you want to search for. This will return the full JSON of that particular product.

If you take a closer look at the URL you provided, you can find a lot of these endpoints you can try out on.

Again, you must have an `access_token` that you generate by having an app installed and authorized to read products in the scope. Also, you must place it in the correct header I mentioned.